# how to get these two div's side by side in this container

Tags: html, css

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzkt2hcx/) consisting of this html markup and CSS:

```css
  .embers-info{
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;
  }


  .embers-total{
    width: 80px;
  }

  .embers-email{
    margin-left: 20px;
  }



  .embers-phone{
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
  }

  .embers-notes{
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  }

  .embers-pickup{
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .embers-actions{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .af-commerce{
    float: right;
  }

  .embers-checkout-header{
    padding: 3px 10px 12px 5px;
  }

  .embers-user-info{
    width: 300px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .embers-delivery-info{
    width: 300px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
```

```html
   <div class='embers-info'>
     <div class='embers-user-info'>
  <div class='embers-email'>
    email:<br />
     <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" />
  </div>
  <div class='embers-phone'>
    phone number:<br />
    <input type="text" size="30" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" />
  </div>
  <div class='embers-notes'>
    notes:<br />
    <textarea id='notes' cols='30' rows='5'></textarea>
  </div>
    <div class='embers-pickup'>

  <br />pickup times:<br />
  November 21 10am:<input type="radio" size="30" class="pickup" name="pickup" value="time1" /> <br />
  November 21 noon:<input type="radio" size="30" class="pickup" name="pickup" value="time2" /><br />
  November 21 2pm:<input type="radio" size="30" class="pickup" name="pickup" value="time3" /><br />
  November 21 4pm:<input type="radio" size="30" class="pickup" name="pickup" value="time4" /><br />
  November 22 8am:<input type="radio" size="30" class="pickup" name="pickup" value="time4" /><br />
</div>

  <div class='embers-actions'>
     <button id='save_order'>save order</button>
    <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
   </div>
</div>

<div class='embers-delivery-info'>
  here i am
</div>

</div>
```

and would like to get the blue and red div side-by-side. How would I do this?

I tried to use:

```
display:inline-block;
```

but that didn't matter.

Comment: try adding `display: flex` to `.embers-info`

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has mentioned flexbox, which while a perfectly valid solution may not be what you need depending on your minimum browser requirements as flexbox is still not as well supported as one would like. When aligning elements side by side using traditional methods you have a couple of options, `display: inline-block` and `float`.

`display: inline-block` : http://jsfiddle.net/bzkt2hcx/2/

```
  .embers-info {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .embers-info > div {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Notes: 
`inline-block` elements may be rendered with spacing on some browsers, most notably chrome. To fix this set we can set `font-size: 0` on the parent container and then reset the `font-size` on the children.

`float: left/right`: http://jsfiddle.net/bzkt2hcx/3/

```
  .embers-info {
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .embers-info > div {
      float: left;
  }
```

Notes: floated elements are taken out of the flow and do not affect their parents heights, causing sizing and layout issues. To alleviate this we need to apply a clearfix on the parent, the simplest of which is setting `overflow: auto` on the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox by adding `display: flex` to the containing div.  This will default in a `flex-direction` of row, which will put them next to each other:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzkt2hcx/1/

More reading for laying out the children in a flexbox container:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: oh, nice. has `display:flex` been around a while? Is it well supported. Do I need to shim it for older / mobile browsers?

Comment: Which browsers are you supporting?  You can look here for support:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: yeah, looking into it. The typical answer - modern browsers and hope that somebody doesn't have an old version of Safari.

Comment: Yeah.  Careful with IE10 too.  Its based off an older version of the spec so it uses some old, outdated syntax.

Comment: cool, thx for heads up. I upvoted but will probably go with other answer since I need to  support some old cruft. `display: flex` looks like what I wish I had 10 years ago.